# Как создать список-фильтр на html+css+js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем добрый день!
Как создать выпадающий список-фильтр на html+css+js. Поведение должно быть как на картинке: при нажатии на "крестик" у заданного "фильтра" значение надо сбросить в дефолтное. Стандартные кастомизации элемента select вряд-ли помогут, поэтому начал оформлять просто на div'ах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас код написан как из примера на странице: http://www.rudebox.org.ua/custom-drop-down-list-styling/

Можете ли подсказать как правильно написать js код для очистки результатов  и добавления закрывающего "крестика"

Пример кода:

```js
function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
    this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
    this.val = '';
    this.index = -1;
    this.initEvents();
   }
   DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents : function() {
     var obj = this;

     obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      return false;
     });

     obj.opts.on('click',function(){
      var opt = $(this);
      obj.val = opt.text();
      obj.index = opt.index();
      obj.placeholder.text('' + obj.val);
     });
    },
    getValue : function() {
     return this.val;
    },
    getIndex : function() {
     return this.index;
    }
   }

   $(function() {

    var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );

    $(document).click(function() {
     // all dropdowns
     $('.wrapper-dropdown-1').removeClass('active');
    });

   });
```

```css
.wrapper-dropdown-1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #9bc7de;
    color: #fff;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #fff;
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #9e9e9e;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-1.active {
    background: #9bc7de;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #9bc7de 0%, #9bc7de 78%, #ffffff 78%, #ffffff 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#9bc7de), color-stop(78%,#9bc7de), color-stop(78%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#ffffff));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #9bc7de 0%,#9bc7de 78%,#ffffff 78%,#ffffff 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #9bc7de 0%,#9bc7de 78%,#ffffff 78%,#ffffff 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #9bc7de 0%,#9bc7de 78%,#ffffff 78%,#ffffff 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #9bc7de 0%,#9bc7de 78%,#ffffff 78%,#ffffff 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9bc7de', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 );
}
.wrapper-dropdown-1.active .dropdown {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-1.active::after {
    border-color: #9bc7de transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    margin-top: -3px;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-1::after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 16px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    border-width: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent #fff;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-1" tabindex="1">
      <span>Month:</span>
         <ul class="dropdown" tabindex="1">
             <li><a href="#">Jun</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Feb</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Mar</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Apr</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
         </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте код, а мы посмотрим и поможем

Comment: @Mihanik71 , код добавил. Оформление, конечно, немного не то, но это я чуть позже поправлю, главное сам принцип работы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил функцию добавления значения в список результатов и удаления результатов.

Будут вопросы или уточнения по заданию — пишите.

```js
 function DropDown(el) {
 this.dd = el;
 this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
 this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
 this.result = $('.dropdown-result');
 this.resultClose = $('.dropdown-result .result-block .result-close');
 this.val = '';
 this.index = -1;
 this.initEvents();
 
}
DropDown.prototype = {
 initEvents : function() {
  var obj = this;
  obj.dd.data("value", {});
  obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
   return false;
  });

  obj.opts.on('click',function(){
   var opt = $(this);
   obj.val = opt.text();
   obj.index = opt.index();
   obj.placeholder.text('' + obj.val);
   
   var temp = obj.dd.data("value");
   temp[obj.val] = obj.val;
   obj.dd.data("value",temp);
   
   obj.result.html(obj.result.html()+"<div class='result-block' data-value='"+obj.val+"'>"+obj.val+"<div class='result-close'>x</div></div>");
   $('.result-close').on("click",function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var temp = obj.dd.data("value");
    delete(temp[$(this).parent().data("value")]);
    obj.dd.data("value",temp);

   });
  });
  
  
 },
 getValue : function() {
  return  obj.dd.data("value");
 },
 getIndex : function() {
  return this.index;
 }
}

$(function() {
 var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );
 $(document).click(function() {
  // all dropdowns
  $('.wrapper-dropdown-1').removeClass('active');
 });

});
```

```css
 .wrapper-dropdown-1 {
position: relative;
width: 100px;
padding: 10px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: #9bc7de;
color: #fff;
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
font-weight: bold;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
background: #fff;
list-style: none;
font-weight: normal;
opacity: 0;
pointer-events: none;
text-align: center;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #9e9e9e;
padding: 10px 20px;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-1.active {
background: #9bc7de;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #9bc7de 0%, #9bc7de 78%, #ffffff 78%, #ffffff 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#9bc7de), color-stop(78%,#9bc7de), color-stop(78%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#ffffff));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #9bc7de 0%,#9bc7de 78%,#ffffff 78%,#ffffff 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #9bc7de 0%,#9bc7de 78%,#ffffff 78%,#ffffff 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #9bc7de 0%,#9bc7de 78%,#ffffff 78%,#ffffff 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #9bc7de 0%,#9bc7de 78%,#ffffff 78%,#ffffff 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9bc7de', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 );
}
.wrapper-dropdown-1.active .dropdown {
opacity: 1;
pointer-events: auto;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-1.active::after {
border-color: #9bc7de transparent;
border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
margin-top: -3px;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-1::after {
content: "";
width: 0;
height: 0;
position: absolute;
right: 16px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -6px;
border-width: 6px 0 6px 6px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: transparent #fff;
}

.dropdown-result{
 width:200px;
 background:#eee;
 margin:0 auto;
 color:#333;
 font-size:16px;
}
.dropdown-result .result-block{
 padding:10px 25px 10px 10px;
 margin:15px;
 border:1px solid #999;
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
}
.dropdown-result .result-block .result-close {
 color: #555;
 font-size: 17px;
 height: 17px;
 width: 17px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 right: 0;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-1" tabindex="1">
<span>Month:</span>
<ul class="dropdown" tabindex="1">
 <li><a href="#">Jun</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Feb</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Apr</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="dropdown-result"></div>
```